# How to pass a reference to the object owning the member function from within which a callback was registered to the callback in JS?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

How to pass a reference to the object owning the member function from within which a callback was registered to the callback? ... I'll let the code snipit speak before I try clarifying that sentence!

```
function Foo() {} // class constructor

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:false},
        this._yayCallback, // permission granted callback
        this._nayCallback); // permission denied callback
};

Foo.prototype._yayCallback(stream) {
    this._stream = stream; // need 'this' to be instance of Foo on which bar was called.
};
Foo.prototype._nayCallback(error) {
    window.alert("bah-humbug!");
};

var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(); // Error: _yay/_nayCallback does not exist on global object or some such...
```

The objective is to be able to access the instance that called `Foo.bar()` via 'this' or any other means to add additional data once access has been granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to really understand your issue, but I'll assume it's happening when your `navigator.getUserMedia` is calling its callbacks.

You may want to bind them before passing them :

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:false},
        this._yayCallback.bind(this), // permission granted callback
        this._nayCallback.bind(this)); // permission denied callback
};
```

This way they will get called in the correct context.

Otherwise, once executed, `this` in your callbacks will be the global `Window`.

Just be aware that `Function.prototype.bind()` [supports IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Just found out also that your snippet has errors, it should be :

```
Foo.prototype._yayCallback = function (stream) {};
Foo.prototype._nayCallback = function (error) {};
```

But I guess it wasn't written like that in your code ;)

Comment: Awsome! Did the trick perfectly thanks. (trying to carry program structure over from C++ to JS is breaking the way my head works)... And yeah there were a few edits in the snip-it conversion - although I think I may adopt 'bah-humbug' as my default error message from now on.